# Obj-C, how do I get the height of a sub view to scale, across all iPhone sizes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm having some trouble catering for the new iPhone 5 screen height, I need to resize my table view already to show an advert.

Up till iOS6 I didn't have a problem, I used the following function, but it doesn't use scale. To be honest I'm surprised it works.

```
+ (CGRect)setTableBoundsByHeight:(int)lHeight:(UITableView*)tbl {
    CGRect tableFrame = tbl.frame;
    return CGRectMake(tableFrame.origin.x,
                      tableFrame.origin.y,
                      tableFrame.size.width,
                      lHeight);
}
```

Here's the code, where I have hard coded the height of my table view at 367, that's minus the height of a navigation controller and a tab bar. 50 is the height of the advert.

```
if (!productPurchased) {
#ifdef VER_FREE  
    [[LARSAdController sharedManager] 
           addAdContainerToView:self.view withParentViewController:self];
    [[LARSAdController sharedManager] 
           setGoogleAdPublisherId:@"number"];
    [reportTableView setFrame:[General 
           setTableBoundsByHeight:(367-50):reportTableView]];
#endif
} else {
    [reportTableView setFrame:[General 
           setTableBoundsByHeight:367:reportTableView]];
}
```

I've found some code which scales but I'm not sure how to implement this.

```
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is inside your view controller, just use `self.view.bounds.height` rather than 367.

By the way: You should really rename

```
+ (CGRect)setTableBoundsByHeight:(int)lHeight:(UITableView*)tbl
```

to something like

```
+ (CGRect)setTableBoundsByHeight:(int)lHeight tableView:(UITableView *)tbl
```

Comment: I know that I accepted this answer and indeed it does work on the simulator at 3.5 + 4 size retina, but at standard none retina aka "iPhone" it doesn't scale. I hadn't tried this device option before. Thoughts ?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't scale"?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the scale, it scales automatically. Just check if iPhone 5 and set different height, but you use iphone5 pixel count/2 as it'll scale it to 2x itself.

Comment: ok, but to work out the height of the table I'm still going to need to minus the heights of the navigation bar + tab bar + advert height, which I don't know at the new size.

Answer (score 0):

Using hard-coded values (a.k.a. "magic numbers") is a wrong habit, you see why now. Always prefer using constants or runtime-computed values. Besides, it makes code easier to read because by using constants you will know what the numbers correspond to, instead of being "magic numbers" coming from nowhere.

So for your problem, compute the height value at runtime using this kind of code below.

```
// simply use the height of the current viewController's `view`
// which is probably the view of the `navigationController`'s `topViewController`
// and is already at the correct size, namely 367 in iPhone 3.5" and 455 in iPhone 4".
CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.height;
if (!productPurchased)
{
  static CGFloat advertHeight = 50;
#ifdef VER_FREE  
  [[LARSAdController sharedManager] 
       addAdContainerToView:self.view withParentViewController:self];
  [[LARSAdController sharedManager] 
       setGoogleAdPublisherId:@"number"];
  [reportTableView setFrame:[General 
       setTableBoundsByHeight:(screenHeight-advertHeight):reportTableView]];
#endif
} else {
  [reportTableView setFrame:[General 
       setTableBoundsByHeight:screenHeight:reportTableView]];
}
```

Note that you don't need to do any substraction yourself, as the `UIViewControllers` resize their view according to the space available, so that if you have for example a `UITabBarController` that contains a `UINavigationController` that itself shows a `UIViewController` on top of its stack, the height of this last viewController's `view` will be the height of the screen minus the tabBar, statusBar and navBar heights.

So instead of fetching the `[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame` for example, and subtract the tabBar (if any) and navBar heights to have your value of 367pt, simply use the height of the `viewController`'s `view` directly and you should have the right value directly.

---

Additional note: you should give a prefix to your second argument, thus name your method `setTableBoundsByHeight:tableView:` instead of `setTableBoundsByHeight::` where the second argument does not have any prefix. (See @MrMage answer that suggest this too).

A better naming for your method would even be `setHeight:forTableView:` for example, to beter fit the Apple naming conventions.